# Line tangent to an ellipse in 3d space at a given point

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

I have the ellipse defined by the equation $\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{z^2}{8} = 1$, and I need to find the parametric equation for a line tangent to the ellipse at $(1,2,2)$

I know that the parametric equation for the ellipse is $x = 2cos(t), y=2, z=8sin(t)$, but I'm not sure what to do next.

The original question was

Find parametrization of curve of intersection of following two surfaces
Surface
$4x^2+2y^2+z^2=16$ intersects plane
$y = 2$
and generates an ellipse

Find the parametric equation of the tangent line to this ellipse at
( 1 , 2 , 2 )

Comment: This is different than your last question. I think the question meant equation of tangent line. You should also add the original question text here.

Comment: @saulspatz OP's original question was different that they deleted,  based on which it is an ellipse at $y=2$. That's why I asked OP to add the original question.

Comment: @MathLover Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersection of the given surface and the plane is,

$\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{z^2}{8} = 1, y = 2$ which can be parametrized as

$r(t) = \langle\sqrt2 \ cos (t), 2, \sqrt8 \ sin (t) \ \rangle $

So $r'(t) = \langle - \sqrt2 \ sin (t), 0, \sqrt8 \ cos (t) \ \rangle$

At $(1, 2, 2), x = \sqrt2 \cos (t) = 1, z = \sqrt 8 \sin (t) = 2 \implies t = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

$r'(t = \frac{\pi}{4}) = (-1, 0, 2)$

So the equation of tangent line is $(1,2, 2) + (-1, 0, 2) t$

or $ \ x = 1 - t, y = 2, z = 2 + 2t$

Comment: Unfortunately, my professor just went over this question in lecture, using a different method of solving it, and got a slightly different answer. The correct answer he had was (1,2,2) + (1,0,-2)t. Are these both tangent lines that go through this point, or did someone make a mistake?

Comment: Both are same answer as the $t$ can take all real values. I have taken vector in a direction and multiplied by $t$, the solution in your comment takes vector in opposite direction. Both represent the same line but the point on the line that I get for $t = 1$, the answer in your comment will get for $t = -1$ and vice versa.

Comment: $(1, 0, -2) = - (-1, 0, 2)$